# Could not extract the browser console logs from standalone-chrome-debug docker container

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-console, selenium-docker

I am trying to extract the browser console logs for my tests which are running on standalone-chrome-debug container on different server. I do not get the logs when in run on docker container.

However when i run the same test on my local machine with chrome driver, the logs are getting extracted as expected. Does any one has idea if we can extract the browser console logs for the test running on docker container.

Following way i am trying to achieve this.

```
   LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
   logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);


    public LogEntries getBrowserConsoleLogs() {
        return driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    }
```

Comment: Its been resolved by setting up the following cap

        capabilities.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);